# Can I create folders

Tags: file-management

I have a Samsung Galaxy s6 with Nougat.

Please,I'd like to know if I can create folders in Archive>Documents.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

on stock non rooted phone you cannot make the Archives folder you seem to refer to in root (top level) directory. However you can't even see root dir in many files managers.
So in a file manager, (I use es file explorer, but frankly it's getting bloated, so I dunno what to recommend) just go to sdcard & make an Archive & Documents folder (either way you need them) or just click into them or they're already there. you can also do it from the command line with a terminal emulator. this gives you Linux street cred & will boost your confidence, but more people go the easy way.

```
cd sdcard
cd Documents
mkdir Archive
cd Archive
echo "dear diary, blah blah" > myfile.txt
```